# SQL Server add rows using different foreign key values

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

Say I have 3 tables:

**Table1**:

```
Table1ID (pk) |
Table1Value
```

**Table2**:

```
Table2ID (pk) | Table1ID (fk) | Table2Value
```

**Table3**:

```
Table3Id (pk) | Table2ID (fk) | Table3Value
```

I have data like this:

Table1:

```
1 | Table1Value1
2 | Table1Value2
```

Table2:

```
 1 | 1 | Table2Value1
12 | 1 | Table2Value2
35 | 2 | Table2Value1 (same value as 1st entry above for now)
36 | 2 | Table2Value2 (same value as 2nd entry above for now)
```

Table3:

```
1 | 1 | Table3ValueData1
2 | 12 | Table3ValueData2
```

Now, all I am wanting to do for now is clone the table3 data, but instead set the Table2ID = the id's belonging to the values where table1ID = 2.

I tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Table2ID, Table3Value)
   SELECT 
      Table2ID, Value
   FROM 
      Table3 t3 
   JOIN 
      Table2 t2 on t3.Table2ID = t2.Table2
   WHERE
      Table1ID = 1
```

Unfortunately, this just duplicates the data with the same Table2IDs like this:

```
 1 | 1 | Table3ValueData1
 2 | 12 | Table3ValueData2
52 | 1 | Table3ValueData1
53 | 12 | Table3ValueData2
```

This is what I want the data in Table3 to look like:

```
 1 | 1 | Table3Value1Data1
 2 | 12 | Table3ValueData2
52 | 35 | Table3ValueData1
53 | 36 | Table3ValueData2
```

The data should remain the same for now in Table3, but the foreign keys should now be pointing to different parents (35 and 36 instead of 1 and 12). How do I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are trying to do here. Can you create a sqlfiddle at sqlfiddle.com to get started? It would be much easier to understand what you are trying to with some data instead of this wall of text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on exactly what are you trying to do, but assuming I understand correctly, you can do it like this:

```
insert into Table3
select b.Table2ID, a.Table3Value
from (select t2.Table2Value, t3.Table3Value from Table3 t3 join Table2 t2 on t3.Table2ID = t2.Table2ID) a
join (select Table2ID, Table2Value from Table2 where Table1ID = 2) b on a.Table2Value = b.Table2Value
```

See my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0edbd/1)